# Systematic Literature Review: PRISMA Statement vs. the PRISMA Protocol (aka PRISMA-P) Checklists?

Tags: thesis, literature-review

**Problem**: I am confused about why it matters if one uses the PRISMA Statement 2020 checklist versus the PRISMA-P 2015 checklist for a systematic literature review. Therefore, I am looking to StackExchange members who can offer an explanation, perhaps with contrasting examples, to help.

Should it help inform your answer, the goal is to write a bifurcated SLR with recommendations for resolving inconsistent diagnoses of a specific mental disorder

**Background**: I have spent several hours reading and re-reading about the PRISMA Statement, the PRISMA-P, comparing the checklists side-by-side, and even created a merged table of the checklists.

To me, the checklists are substantially the same. This description of intended/not intended use one checklist vs the other did nothing (for me) to clarify the difference (because, again, there are, to me, no blindingly obvious differences between the checklists).

> PRISMA 2020 is not intended to inform the reporting of systematic review protocols, for which a separate statement is available (PRISMA for Protocols (PRISMA-P) 2015 statement.
> *From  [The PRISMA 2020 statement: an updated guideline for reporting systematic reviews
> BMJ 2021; 372 (Published 29 March 2021)](https://doi.org/10.1136/bmj.n71) *

**Additional Links**

[Table 2 PRISMA-P terminology](https://systematicreviewsjournal.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/2046-4053-4-1/tables/2)

[PRISMA 2020 Statement Checklist](https://www.prisma-statement.org//documents/PRISMA_2020_checklist.docx)

[PRISMA-P 2015 Checklist](https://prisma-statement.org/documents/PRISMA-P-checklist.doc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes it takes writing a post to StackExchange for the lightbulbs to come on. At least I think the lightbulbs are now on.

While cleaning up the merged checklists for readability, it occurred to me that for thesis purposes:

- The PRISMA-P 2015 is a checklist for writing the proposed method.
- The PRISMA 2020 statement is a checklist for writing the research results.
- Either checklist could be adapted by merging items from the other to customize the proposed method or to customize the reporting of the results.

*Note*: Yes, I am aware that the checklists were created to promote consistency. So, of course, if any adaptations are made, one has to be able to defend doing so.